# I am trying get date as a String type from a DateChooserPanel and show the date on a textfield

Tags: java, swing

I can't seem to get the date from the DateChooserPanel...

I want to choose a date from DateChooserPanel and I want to show the selected date to the textfield.

How can I get the date from DateChooserPanel in a String type?

I tried to change the date format into string but didn't work.

Am I using datechooser correctly??

The error says the it cannot format given object as a Date...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.text.Caret;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import datechooser.beans.DateChooserPanel;
import datechooser.beans.DateChooserDialog;
import datechooser.beans.DateChooserCombo;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class SetTime {

    private JFrame frame;
    private DateChooserPanel dateChooserPanel_1;
    private JTextField textField;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    SetTime window = new SetTime();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
     }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public SetTime() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        this.frame = new JFrame();
        this.frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        this.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        this.dateChooserPanel_1 = new DateChooserPanel();
        this.dateChooserPanel_1.setBounds(12, 44, 250, 180);
        this.frame.getContentPane().add(this.dateChooserPanel_1);

        this.textField = new JTextField();
        this.textField.setBounds(306, 113, 116, 21);
        this.frame.getContentPane().add(this.textField);
        this.textField.setColumns(10);

        Calendar date = dateChooserPanel_1.getSelectedDate();

        String strdate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(date);

        textField.setText(strdate);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you're trying to pass a Calendar object into a method that requires a Date object.

To get a Date from your Calendar call

```
Date selectedDate = date.getTime();
```

Then you can use

```
String strdate = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(selectedDate);
```